# Is it possible to login to accounts if you have access to an android phone?

Tags: passwords, android

Similarly if you have access to a PC you can steal session cookies which allows you to login without password and without the login showing in login logs.

If one has access to an android device is it possible to do something similar, I know apps dont work the same as web apllications but still is there a method similar.

This is purely for education purposes.

Comment: Many apps actually work the same as web applications. As for the others there is no single alternative way of doing it which means that there is no single way to exploit it either. But the general idea of intercepting the communication and using these intercepted information to steal the identity works probably for many applications, i.e. there is either some session cookie or authentication token or similar.

Comment: I don't know why people write "This is purely for educational purposes". If we thought you were up to something criminal, do you really think that this small disclaimer would change anything?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Steffen says, mobile apps work very similar to web applications. Sometimes they consume the same APIs and use the same authentication/authorization scheme (e.g. API keys). This information needs to be stored somewhere, especially for apps that stay persistently logged in.

Most apps store sensitive information in the app's protected directory in `/data`, which other apps cannot read without root access. You may be out of luck unless the device is rooted, there is an RCE vulnerability in the application, the app's comms are not properly encrypted, or the target app allows debugging.

Additionally, most modern Android devices use user-data encryption at rest. So, a powered off phone (or even one with a custom recovery) is no good for circumventing permissions and recovering data.